# Coordinate expression of second term in tensor Laplacian

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, tensors, laplacian

In [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%E2%80%93Beltrami_operator#Tensor_Laplacian), the Laplacian of any tensor is given as

$\Delta T = g^{ij}(\nabla_i\nabla_j T - \nabla_{\nabla_i e_j}T)$

As I see it, since $\nabla_i{e_j}$ is a vector, we can apply

$\nabla_{V^k e_k}T = V^k \nabla_kT$

and since $\nabla_i{e_j}$ is also the connection,

$\nabla_i{e_j} \equiv \Gamma^k_{ij}e_k$

we end up with

$\nabla_{\nabla_i{e_j}}T = \Gamma^k_{ij}\nabla_k T$

Is that valid?  I'm not too confident with differential geometry manipulations, and I didn't see the Laplacian written in coordinate form anywhere.  But the rest of it is just coordinate covariant derivatives, which should be more straightforward.

Comment: That's fine. But the first equation is in local coordinate!

Comment: You mean the equation for $\Delta T$?  But I can still apply it at every point of a global coordinate system, right?